# HEAD requests fail after switching to HTTP/2

Tags: google-chrome, network-protocols, http2

I have a strange problem after my webhost switched to HTTP/2.

Suddenly all HEAD requests to PHP pages cause an ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR in Chrome. This even happens when the file is empty. This only seems to happen in Chrome though, Postman and Lynx seem to be able to send the request just fine.

An example, entering the following in the console in Chrome (the test.php file is empty):

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("HEAD", "https://play.asti.ga/api/test.php");
http.send();
```

returns the following error:
`HEAD https://play.asti.ga/api/test.php net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR`
The network tab also shows `(failed)`. However, doing the same request to test.html does work like it should.

I contacted the webhost, and they claim that their configuration is fine, so I was wondering what I can do to fix this. The server runs on PHP/7.0.25

Comment: `curl --head https://play.asti.ga/api/test.php` returns `curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)` -- That's not coming from PHP.

Comment: From curl's verbose option: `* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0` -- perhaps it's got something to do with the proxy receiving zero bytes from the upstream host.

Comment: Hmm nevermind, a GET request also has the same `len=0` message, but works fine...

Comment: Note, if you request the same page via HTTP, it works fine. That pretty clearly shows the problem is with the web server configuration, and not with your app.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you for looking into it. I will contact my webhost again (there have been quite a few emails back and forth already), hopefully they can fix it this time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It did turn out to be a server problem, more specifically a problem with SuPHP in combination with HTTP/2.